# How can I make my StackPane take up the full vertical height of the window?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, borderpane

I'm trying to make the StackPane located in the `<left>` element of my main BorderPane take up the full vertical height of the window, even when its resized. How can I do this? This is what I've got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox prefWidth="800.0" prefHeight="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
        <ToolBar minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="800.0" stylesheets="@style.css" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                <Image url="@react-toolbar-logo.png"/>
            </ImageView>
        </ToolBar>
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0"/>
    </VBox>

    <BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

        <left>
            <StackPane prefWidth="230">
                <ListView fx:id="listView"/>
            </StackPane>
        </left>
        <right>
            <StackPane>
                <ScrollPane>
                    <Group fx:id="selectionGroup">
                        <ImageView fx:id="mainImageView"/>
                    </Group>
                </ScrollPane>
            </StackPane>
        </right>

    </BorderPane>
</VBox>
```

Comment: The full height of the *window* or the full height of the *BorderPane*? The VBox with top_center alignment will prevent you from doing the former (unless you reorganise things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack pane (and consequently the `ListView`: I'm not sure why you need to wrap the `ListView` in a `StackPane`) already *is* filling the full height of the border pane. You can see this, e.g. by changing the background color of the border pane. The issue is that the border pane is not growing to fill all the available space in the surrounding `VBox`.

If you want to let the `BorderPane` fill the remaining space, set its `VBox.vgrow` property to `ALWAYS`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.Double?>

<VBox prefWidth="800.0" prefHeight="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
        <ToolBar minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="800.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                <Image url="@react-toolbar-logo.png"/>
            </ImageView>
        </ToolBar>
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0"/>

    </VBox>

    <BorderPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">

        <left>
            <StackPane prefWidth="230">
                <ListView fx:id="listView" />
            </StackPane>

        </left>
        <right>
            <StackPane>
                <ScrollPane>
                    <Group fx:id="selectionGroup">
                        <ImageView fx:id="mainImageView"/>
                    </Group>
                </ScrollPane>
            </StackPane>
        </right>

    </BorderPane>

</VBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind the corresponding values. If you want to have a child always fill the size of its parent, then you can bind the `prefHeightProperty` of the child to the `heightProperty` of its parent.
That is possible in java code like

`child.prefHeightProperty().bind(parent.heightProperty);`

or in fxml like

`<ListView fx:id="listView" prefHeight="${listView.parent.width}"/>`

Check out [Oracle's description about bindings…](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm)

Comment: Binding properties to adjust the layout always seems like a hack to me. Use properties of the layout panes, or settings on the child nodes directly, to affect the layout.

Comment: Though it may appear hackish, it may exactly do what you want in many situations. You are right, @James_D, there may be less hackish possibilities.

Comment: Just think about what happens behind the scenes, though. During a layout pass, the height of the list view's parent is likely determined by its pref height, which is determined by the pref height of its child nodes. If you bind the pref height of the child node to the height of the parent, you are really working against the way layout is performed in JavaFX, at best, and potentially risk creating infinite recursion or layout that changes on every layout pass, at worst.

Comment: Also, it won't make any difference in this case, since the list view/stack pane growing is not actually the problem anyway :).

Answer (score 1):

It *sounds* like you want to restructure your layout like so, but I think you may need to clarify exactly what you're after.

```
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <left>
        <StackPane> ... </StackPane>
    </left>
    <right>
        <StackPane> ... </StackPane>
    </right>
    <top>
        <VBox>
            <ToolBar> ... </ToolBar>
            <MenuBar> ... </MenuBar>
        <VBox>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: James_D's answer ultimately resolved my vertical stretching requirement. :), but this is a lot cleaner than what I have. I moved my top components into the BorderPane. Thanks.